# Windows MDM server SyncML protocol implementation

Tags: windows-phone-8, mdm, syncml, oma

I am new to Windows MDM server and still learning it, so my question can be a little naive so please bear with it :)

I trying to develop windows MDM server. I have gone through Windows MDM protocol document, SyncML document and MOF files. But I am yet not sure about the syntax for Commands like ADD, Replace. How the data will be sent to device in  ...  in SyncML for various MOF classes.

It was very clear in one of the example provided in doc for sending certificate. But have not given clear examples for sending data such as wifi profile as a data. Will it be key val pair of just comma seperated list in

If anyone has already working mdm server and would like to share sample SyncML formated command will be very helpful in my case.

Comment: Yeah.... stuck with the same.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Example for adding Wifi with proxy

```
<SyncML
xmlns="SYNCML:SYNCML1.2"
xmlns:ns2="syncml:metinf">
<SyncHdr>
    <VerDTD>1.2</VerDTD>
    <VerProto>DM/1.2</VerProto>
    <SessionID>7</SessionID>
    <MsgID>2</MsgID>
    <Target>
        <LocURI>urn:uuid:E4544F96-AA41-5E12-B8C5-4C3CEF6E1822</LocURI>
    </Target>
    <Source>
        <LocURI>https://www.examplemdm.com/1/</LocURI>
    </Source>
</SyncHdr>
<SyncBody>
    <Status>
        <CmdID>1</CmdID>
        <MsgRef>2</MsgRef>
        <CmdRef>0</CmdRef>
        <Cmd>SyncHdr</Cmd>
        <Data>200</Data>
    </Status>
    <Sequence>
        <CmdID>POL_WIFI</CmdID>
        <Atomic>
            <CmdID>PROXY_WIFI_PSK_1</CmdID>
            <Add>
                <CmdID>WIN_POL_WIFI_WPA_WPA2_PSK_1</CmdID>
                <Item>
                    <Target>
                        <LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/WiFi/Profile/MY%20NETWORK/WlanXml</LocURI>
                    </Target>
                    <Meta>
                        <ns2:Format>chr</ns2:Format>
                    </Meta>
                    <Data>&lt;WLANProfile
                        xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1"&gt;&lt;name&gt;Mits Laptop&lt;/name&gt;&lt;SSIDConfig&gt;&lt;SSID&gt;&lt;name&gt;Mits Laptop&lt;/name&gt;&lt;/SSID&gt;&lt;nonBroadcast&gt;false&lt;/nonBroadcast&gt;&lt;/SSIDConfig&gt;&lt;connectionType&gt;ESS&lt;/connectionType&gt;&lt;connectionMode&gt;auto&lt;/connectionMode&gt;&lt;autoSwitch&gt;false&lt;/autoSwitch&gt;&lt;MSM&gt;&lt;security&gt;&lt;authEncryption&gt;&lt;authentication&gt;WPA2PSK&lt;/authentication&gt;&lt;encryption&gt;TKIP&lt;/encryption&gt;&lt;useOneX&gt;false&lt;/useOneX&gt;&lt;/authEncryption&gt; &lt;sharedKey&gt;&lt;keyType&gt;passPhrase&lt;/keyType&gt;&lt;protected&gt;false&lt;/protected&gt;&lt;keyMaterial&gt;myPassword&lt;/keyMaterial&gt;&lt;/sharedKey&gt;&lt;/security&gt;&lt;/MSM&gt;&lt;/WLANProfile&gt;
                    </Data>
                </Item>
            </Add>
            <Add>
                <CmdID>add_proxy</CmdID>
                <Item>
                    <Target>
                        <LocURI>./Vendor/MSFT/WiFi/Profile/MY NETWORK/Proxy</LocURI>
                    </Target>
                    <Meta>
                        <ns2:Format>chr</ns2:Format>
                    </Meta>
                    <Data>192.168.1.228:8888</Data>
                </Item>
            </Add>
        </Atomic>
    </Sequence>
    <Final/>
</SyncBody>
```